# Grails 'run-app' is hanging after clean on Jenkins job

Tags: tomcat, grails, jenkins

I've got a Jenkins job that is building and running a Grails app. When I do my `grails run-app` command in my job's shell script, everything works fine normally. However, if I run `grails clean` before running the app, the `run-app` command hangs. I'm noticing that, when it hangs, my `grails-resources` folder is not being created in `target/tomcat/work/Tomcat/localhost/_/`. So it is hanging before whatever step of the compiliation creates that folder.

I'm unable to re-create this on my local machine

It may be relevant (or not) that I'm running `grails run-app` as a daemon. I'm not running `grails clean` using a daemon though.

The `run-app` command is hanging at this point:

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.7
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to jenkins
| Environment set to jenkins.
| Environment set to jenkins..
| Environment set to jenkins...
| Environment set to jenkins....
| Environment set to jenkins.....
| Packaging Grails application
eventCompileStart
version: f4a9fe3
| Packaging Grails application.
| Packaging Grails application..
| Packaging Grails application...
| Packaging Grails application....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files...
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI
```

Please let me know if there is any other information I can give you to help me debug this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to cleanup the workspace before every build? Not sure whether it would be a option for you.

Comment: My project is very large, so deleting the workspace after the build would make the download of the repo every time incredibly long.

Comment: I was able to get this working by doing a `grails compile` command after the  `clean` before `run-app`. Not sure why that works, but it does.